# Embedded Jetty with https : Invalid keystore format

Tags: https, jetty, wicket, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to get my embedded Jetty 8.1.4 (no I can go higher!) server to work with **https**. I generate my keystore with the following command :

```
keytool -genkey -alias sitename -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore -keysize 2048
```

My problem is that when I run this, I get a nice exception!

```
WARN - AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED SslContextFactory@160b6dff(null,null): java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:633)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1183)
```

I tried generating the keystore following different online guides but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks,

AW

Here's the server code :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Server server = new Server();

    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    server.setGracefulShutdown(ALLOWED_SHUTDOWN_TIME);

    Resource keystore = Resource.newClassPathResource("/keystore");

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();

    sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(keystore);
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("wicket");
    sslContextFactory.setTrustStoreResource(keystore);
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("wicket");

    SslSelectChannelConnector connector = new SslSelectChannelConnector(sslContextFactory);

    connector.setMaxIdleTime(30000);
    connector.setPort(getServerPort());
    connector.setAcceptors(4);

    connector.setReuseAddress(false);

    server.addConnector(connector);

    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
    context.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");

    context.getSessionHandler().getSessionManager().setMaxInactiveInterval(60 * 15);
    context.getSessionHandler().getSessionManager().setSessionTrackingModes(newHashSet(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));

    final FilterHolder openSessionInViewFilter = new FilterHolder(new OpenSessionInViewFilter());

    context.addFilter(openSessionInViewFilter, "/", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    final FilterHolder wicketFilter = new FilterHolder(WicketFilter.class);

    wicketFilter.setInitParameter(WicketFilter.FILTER_MAPPING_PARAM, "/*");
    wicketFilter.setInitParameter("applicationFactoryClassName", "org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory");

    wicketFilter.setInitParameter("configuration", "development");

    context.addFilter(wicketFilter, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    context.getInitParams().put("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring/spring-config.xml");

    context.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener());

    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();

    } catch (Exception exception) {

        exception.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jetty 8 is now EOL (End of Life) - your question will be more relevant if you use something that is at least somewhat current and actively being used by the majority.

Comment: What was the final solution of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to SSL and the web, you **HAVE TO STAY CURRENT** both in the JVM and the Server software.  The rapid changes in what is supported in SSL in the browser, proxies, hardware, etc.. force you to.

For example, Jetty 8.1.4 was created back in the days of SSL v1, SSL v2 were popular.  Today, SSL is pretty much deprecated (all the way to SSL v3), replaced with TLS with NPN/ALPN being increasingly popular.

Newer versions of Jetty have even deprecated various cipher suites that cause problems online.

Even the Certificate Authorities (CA) are moving in directions that render the older SSLs irrelevant, making it almost impossible to get a Certificate that will work with these old environments.